# Problems increasing an integer in android studio

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am making an android studio app and am trying to get my screen to loop through the digits 0-9 until the user clicks and stops the loop on a particular number. The code I have written so far is:

```
public void loop () {
        for (int a = 0; a<10; a = ++a % 10) {
            textView2.setText("" + a);
        }
```

Relevant xml section

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="0"
android:id="@+id/textView2"
.../>
```

This code doesn't output anything onscreen. I have tried a few different variations of the code and if it does display a number, it only displays the last digit, '9'. This makes me think that it has worked but it goes through the numbers too quickly for me to see and stops on the last one instead of looping indefinitely. Is anyone able to point out where I may be going wrong? I'm still learning so apologies for the relatively simple query.

Also when I do get it to work, and I want to make it clickable, do I put the onclicklistener in the for-loop?

Many thanks.

Comment: You also can do that in asynctask or in thread;), because at now you see only last number, because operation take few miliseconds. When you add asynctask/thread you can use sleep method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, when it displays 9, it just looped through the numbers very quickly, you couldn't even see them changing.

You are not doing anything wrong, you just have to take pauses between changing the numbers. The very easy and ugly fix would be adding: `wait(1000)` after the `setText(...)` method.

However, this is not recommended, because Android draws and receives events on the main thread. When you block the thread for 1000 milliseconds with the `wait`, you make the thread unable to accept any events for that one second, which makes your app freeze.

To fix the freezing, you need to update your `TextView`, and then post a message on the main thread, that it should update again over 1 second. Because of the separation, it won't really look like a loop.

For posting messages on the main thread, I will use a `Handler` (`android.os.Handler`), which executes messages on the thread it was created, unless you use a different `Looper`.

Here's a rough example:

```
private int a = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private TextView textView2;

public void loop() {
     handler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             updateText();
             a = a++ % 10;
             if (a < 10) {
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
             }
         }
     });
}

public void updateText() {
    textView2.setText("" + a);
}
```

Just call `loop()` when the button was clicked, the rest will be handled automatically.